# Docker caching for travis builds

Tags: docker, travis-ci

Docker caching is not yet available on travis: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5358

I'm trying to write a workaround by doing:

```
`docker save -o file.tar $(docker history -q image_name | grep -v missing)`
`docker load -i file.tar
```

Which works great, gives me all the image layers back. My only problem now is the saving takes a long time, and most of the time I'm actually changing one layer, so I don't need to rewrite all the rest. Is there a way of telling the `docker save` command to skip layers already in `file.tar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `manifest.json` file inside the tar you have the information you need.

`tar -xOf file.tar manifest.json`

Check the value of the `Config` keys. The first 12 characters are the image id. You can use the command above, extract the image ids that you already have, and exclude them in your `docker save` command.

I'm not very good with bash scripting, but this works on my mac

`tar -xOf file.tar manifest.json | tr , '\n' | grep -o '"Config":".*"' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | awk '{print substr($0,2,12)}'`

Using this outputs everything

`docker history -q IMAGE_HERE | grep -v missing && tar -xOf file.tar manifest.json | tr , '\n' | grep -o '"Config":".*"' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | awk '{print substr($0,2,12)}'`

After this you only need to get the unique values. This could be done with `sort` and `uniq -u`, but for some reason, sort doesn't work as expected. This command assumes the presence of `file.tar` so take that into consideration too.

I couldn't find anything about append in the docker save command. The above strategy could work with multiple file tars that are all different with each other.

Comment: Great, I didn't know about the manifest file. I accepted the answer, but will try to cook up a script that tars up the diff only.